# How configure EntityManager service name in breeze?

Tags: mongodb, breeze

Breeze.js examples show client code like:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterIntance("dataService","mongo", true);
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName: "breeze/xyz")
```

Somehow breeze has to figure out that the correct URL to fetch the metadata is `http://localhost:8888/breeze/xyz/Metadata`. But configured as above, this fails for me: *"Metadata query failed for breeze/xyz/Metadata"*. It fails because jQuery is issuing:

```
GET file:///C:/dev/xyz/public/breeze/xyz/Metadata
```

To make it work, what I have to do instead is:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService","mongo", true);
serviceName = "http://localhost:8888/breeze/xyz";
var mongoDataService = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: serviceName,
    adapterName: "mongo",
    hasServerMetadata: true 
});
var store = new breeze.MetadataStore();
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    serviceName: serviceName,
    dataService: mongoDataService,
    metadataStore: store
});
```

Is there a way to configure the breeze client so it knows to prepend `http://localhost:8888/` to the service name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several typos but if I look past them what strikes me is the AJAX URL beginning "file:///C:/dev/xyz ...".   That indicates that you are serving the client application from the files system, not a web server. What is the protocol of the URL in the browser when you runt the app? Is it "file:"?

Comment: That was it.  I was double-clicking on "index.html" to bring it up in Chrome. When I do http://localhost:8888/Index.html, it works as expected.  Thanks!